# PhoneGap splash screen

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

Is there anybody can help me with splash screen. 
I created my index.html using jquery mobile , everthing is fine but i need a splash screen.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Mobilizm</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body onload="onLoad()">
        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
                <h3>Mobilizm</h3>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <ul data-role="listview">
                        <li><a href="Reservation.html">Rezervasyon Yap</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Rezervasyonlarımı Gör</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Bilgilerim</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div data-theme="b" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                <h3>Mobilizm</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I added my config.xml file but when ı open my application , there is no splash screen

Any ideas?

Config XML :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <widget xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id = "HelloWorld.Application"
        version = "1.0.0"
        versionCode = "1">

    <name>Mobilizm</name>

    <description>
        Mobilizm mobile application for android
    </description>

    <author href="#" email="polattt@gmail.com">
        Daniele Veneroni
    </author>


    <!-- SPLASH SCREENS -->

    <gap:splash src="css/splash/splash.png" /> <!-- default 320x480 pixels -->

    <!--<gap:splash src="css/splash/ios/splash320x480.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480" /> --><!-- iPhone 3G, 3GS, iPod Touch 2, 3 --><!--
    <gap:splash src="css/splash/ios/splash640x960.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960" /> --><!-- iPhone 4, 4S, iPod Touch 4 --><!--
    <gap:splash src="css/splash/ios/splash640x1136.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136" /> --><!-- iPhone 5, iPod Touch 5 --><!--
    <gap:splash src="css/splash/ios/splash1024x768.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768" /> --><!-- iPad 1, 2, iPad mini --><!--
    <gap:splash src="css/splash/ios/splash768x1024.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024" /> --><!-- iPad 1, 2, iPad mini --><!--
    <gap:splash src="css/splash/ios/splash2048x1496.png" gap:platform="ios" width="2048" height="1496" /> --><!-- iPad 3, 4 --><!--
    <gap:splash src="css/splash/ios/splash1536x2008.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1536" height="2008" /> --><!-- iPad 3, 4 -->

    <gap:splash src="css/splash/android/ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" /> <!-- 200x320 -->
    <gap:splash src="css/splash/android/mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" /> <!-- 320x480 -->
    <gap:splash src="css/splash/android/hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" /> <!-- 480x800 -->
    <gap:splash src="css/splash/android/xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" /> <!-- 720x1280 -->



    <!-- GENERAL PREFERENCES -->

    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="2.9.0" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="default" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" /> <!-- remove the upper bar on iOS and Android -->

    <!-- iOS PREFERENCES -->

    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
    <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque" />
    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="false" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="false" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" /> <!-- if set to false, the splash screen must be hidden using a JavaScript API -->

    <!-- ANDROID PREFERENCES -->

    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="7" /> <!-- minimum Android 2.1 --> 
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <preference name="splash-screen-duration" value="3000" />
    <preference name="load-url-timeout" value="20000" />

    <!-- BLACKBERRY PREFERENCES -->

    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />

    <!-- PHONEGAP API FEATURES PREFERENCES -->

    <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>

</widget>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need any script .you just add image in src folder as in native application in android..

Comment: Yes ravi,you're right. No script is neccessary for splash screen

Answer (score 2):

Mastazi thanks for ur interest ,

i finally solved the issue. There is no script needed.  After changing the size of the images it worked. i edited my xml above

Comment: Oh yes, you are right, the show and hide methods can be used optionally but are not required. I'm sorry my answer wasn't the right one. I suggest you mark your own answer (this one) as accepted answer, it is useful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE this is NOT the right answer. See the OP's own answer.

It looks like you didn't write the javascript to load the splashcreen inside the `head` tag. Something like (example taken from the documentation at http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html ):

```
    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.splashscreen.show();
}
```

Comment: Do I need to write it or it automatically reads the config xml?

Comment: Yes you do, have a look at the documentation in the link that I provided. Be sure to read also the rest of the page as there are some setups that you need to do depending on your platform (iOS / Android)

Comment: i added the script and cordova.js for android, nevertheless nothing is changed.

Comment: Also i use build.phonegap.com to get the app. Here is the link https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml

Answer (score 0):

Just add this in your java file :
splash is your PNG file's name in folders : drawable

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl(),3000);
    }
```